# curl and file_get_contents both cannot find server by domain name set in hosts file

Tags: php, curl, alias, file-get-contents, hosts

On both the PHP server and the client I have in `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.1.111    my-fake-domain-name.com
```

The PHP server *is* that box (192.168.1.111). But when I use `curl` or `file_get_contents` to get anything from that alias (`my-fake-domain-name.com`) it always returns a 403 error. If I use the ip address, everything works fine. How do I get those programs to recognize the alias?

```
//These do NOT work
file_get_contents( "http://my-fake-domain-name.com" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://my-fake-domain-name.com" );

//These DO work
file_get_contents( "http://192.168.1.111" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.111" );
```

**EDIT:** Using `curl` at the command line works with the alias. It's only in PHP that it doesn't seem to work.

** EDIT: Added the config file and what OS I'm using**

OS: CentOS 6.5 Server

**httpd.conf**

```
ServerTokens Prod

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

PidFile run/httpd.pid

Timeout 60

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    12
MaxSpareServers    24
ServerLimit        24
MaxClients         24
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

Listen 80
Listen 443

LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so


Include conf.d/*.conf


User apache
Group apache


ServerAdmin root@localhost

ServerName localhost

UseCanonicalName Off

DocumentRoot "/var/www/public_html"

<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
      #CacheEnable disk /
      #CacheRoot /webaps/cache/app1
      #CacheDefaultExpire 3600
      #CacheDisable /wp-admin
      #CacheDirLevels 3
      #CacheDirLength 5
      #CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
      #CacheMaxFileSize 1000000000
      #CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
      #CacheMaxExpire 1209600
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/public_html/wp-content/plugins">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/public_html">

    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.1

</Directory>

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    #
    # UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
    # of a username on the system (depending on home directory
    # permissions).
    #
    UserDir disabled

    #
    # To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
    # directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
    # the following line instead:
    # 
    #UserDir public_html

</IfModule>


DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off



ErrorLog /webaps/logs/app1/error_log

LogLevel warn

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

CustomLog /webaps/logs/app1/access_log combined

ServerSignature Off

Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8

AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif


ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html

IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t

AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw

LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW

ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8



AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl



AddHandler type-map var

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml




Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
    AllowOverride None
    Options IncludesNoExec
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    AddHandler type-map var
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    LanguagePriority en es de fr
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>


</IfModule>
</IfModule>

BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443


<VirtualHost *:80>
    SSLEngine Off
            ServerName my-fake-domain-name.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: @RoyalBg Why? Using `curl` at the command line works with the host alias. There must be a way to make it work.

Comment: @JakeGould `curl -I` outputs a 403 error as well! Under my httpd.conf, I have `ServerAlias my-fake-domain-name.com` in the virtual host but it's still doing this. (and I restarted the httpd service)

Comment: @JakeGould sorry, so many questions, I missed some. I'm using CentOS 6.5 Server. Running Apache.

Comment: @JakeGould I added the httpd.conf to my question and also the OS I'm using. Apologies for not including them earlier.

Comment: @JakeGould I solved it and added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following, makes both `curl` and `file_get_contents` able to reach the web server:

```
<Directory "/var/www/public_html">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This needs to be added to both the `:80` and `:443` virtual host declarations.

**Note: I'm not sure why this was needed as I previously had `Allow from 192.168.1` and this server is within that**

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `curl -I` for that domain? That should show you the headers with a possible explanation. Run it like this:

```
curl -I my-fake-domain-name.com
```

And what shows up in the web server (I assume Apache?) logs on the server at `my-fake-domain-name.com`? These logs should be located in:

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

And you can follow their output using `tail` like so:

```
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/apache2/access.log
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

These paths are based on a standard Ubuntu 12.04 install, but should be the same for CentOS & whatever Linux variant you are using if you are on Linux.

Assuming it is Apache running on the server, do you have Apache name-based virtual hosts in place?  It could be you are getting a success for `192.168.1.111` because that is the Apache default config returning data, but of you have an Apache name-based virtual host config in place for `my-fake-domain-name.com` and that Apache config is broken it could cause the `403: Forbidden` error.

**EDIT:** And since the original poster in the comments indicates the issue could be with the PHP code itself, there could be an error within the PHP code itself that could cause the 403. Perhaps `.htaccess` related as well?

**ANOTHER EDIT:** In your comments you say you have `ServerAlias` set like so:

```
ServerAlias my-fake-domain-name.com
```

But you seem to be missing `ServerName`:

```
ServerName my-fake-domain-name.com
```

This is a pseudo-code example of how I would setup a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my-fake-domain-name.com/site/
  ServerName my-fake-domain-name.com
  ServerAlias my-fake-domain-name.com

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/my-fake-domain-name.com.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my-fake-domain-name.coml.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You might be onto something, I'm not sure how to fix. When I run (command line) `curl http://my-fake-domain-name.com` it shows the HTML. But when I run `curl -I http://my-fake-domain-name.com` it shows the 403 error!

Comment: It is Apache and in the virtual host, I have `ServerAlias    my-fake-domain-name.com` but it's still doing this.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what your Apache configuration looks like for that virtual host entry. You need to make sure you have both

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.111:80
```

And

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.111:80>
```

in your configuration, and THEN you can put it as `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`, but without seeing your configuration, there's no way for me to tell you what's wrong with it.  You must have ServerName.  For example, you would use `ServerName mydomain.com` and then have `ServerAlias www.mydomain.com subdomain.mydomain.com` under ServerAlias...not sure why you're talking about using Alias unless you already have a domain using that IP

Comment: I have `NameVirtualHost *:80` and '<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: So is this the only virtualhost entry you have?  Without you providing the entire virtualHost entry it will make it 10x harder to answer this question.  Just change the info you're concerned about and give us a link to a pastebin

Comment: I own a hosting company, and no it's not the best especially if you plan on having more than one site.  The ONLY time that is optimal is when you have ONE site.

Comment: @Myles All I have is th `80` and `443` virtual host configurations and they have nothing in there other than SSQLEngine Off (on for 443) and now the ServerName and ServerAlias.

Comment: So yeah in your case having it as wildcard is fine as JakeGould pointed out.  You did run "service httpd restart" or "service apache2 restart" depending on your installation, right?  Have you tried from your computer with setting the host file and just opening a website to make sure it works?

Comment: @Myles yes, I did run the `service httpd restart` and it didn't work. Also, I am able to reach the web server from that same server using the hosts alias name.

Answer (score 0):

As from your last comment once you changed access to `Allow from all` that fixed your problem.

I'v seen this a few times but what you could try is adding a trailing period:

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.
```

Notice the trailing `.` at the end of the IP

You could also try using CIDR notation:

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

Or just use the full subnet:

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```