# file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, laravel-5, virtualhost, file-get-contents, intervention

I am using intervention package of laravel to upload images and I have created a virtual host staging server where I have hosted my project.
Intervention is working fine when I am using it on local machine with virtual host.

I am getting below error:

> ErrorException in AbstractDecoder.php line 64: file_get_contents():
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Which is in below code in \vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder.php

```
/**
 * Init from fiven URL
 *
 * @param  string $url
 * @return \Intervention\Image\Image
 */
public function initFromUrl($url)
{
    if ($data = file_get_contents($url)) {
        return $this->initFromBinary($data);
    }

    throw new \Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException(
        "Unable to init from given url (".$url.")."
    );
}
```

I think file_get_content gives problem when we work on virtual host.
I have referred this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462063/curl-and-file-get-contents-both-cannot-find-server-by-domain-name-set-in-hosts-f) but I didn't get solution.

Comment: This looks like a DNS issue. Would you please try to pass the URL as an IP address instead of a server name. If this works then it will surely be a DNS issue and then we'll work to fix that.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida It worked with IP. Not working with virtual host's fake domain name.

Comment: Then we have a DNS issue, as I previously said. What operational system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7 for both server and local system from where I am accessing project.

Comment: Then you must edit the file where Windows 7 resolves local DNS names and map the IPs to the corresponding virtual servers. Please read this: http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/edit-hosts-file/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : file\_get\_contents($loc) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542046/php-file-get-contentsloc-fails)

Answer (score 1):

If `file_get_contents` works when you use IPs but not when you use virtual host names, then we have a DNS issue here.

If you were using Linux you should edit (as root) the file `/etc/hosts` and map there the names of your virtual servers to the corresponding IPs and then restart your DNS servers.

But you are using Windows 7, then you must do the same in the file `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and then restart your machine machine.

If you have doubts about how to find/edit this file, please read [this article here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/edit-hosts-file/).

Comment: I have already added IP     fake-name.me in my hosts file. On server and local both. That means I should just restart my server to make it work?

Comment: Do you use a local DNS server?

Comment: I believe Windows 7 has one, but you must check in your services if it is active.